# White space at page bottom after device rotation in iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

I have a website with a meta tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

and `height:100%;` on `html` and `body` tags.

When I access this site from Safari (iOS 13.5.1) and do the following:

- rotate my device to the landscape mode
- then rotate it back to the portrait mode

then a white space appears on the bottom of the screen. This space is not a part of the page html code. It is outside of the `html` tag.

[image]

**Minimum reproducible example: https://jsbin.com/cojabiquza**

This seems to be related to the Safari behaviour when it hides the address panel and the bottom panel when the device goes to the landscape mode. And when it goes back to the portrait mode the panels are shown again but the browser "forgets" to recalculate something and shows an extra space on the bottom of the page.

Deleting `<meta name="viewport"...` fixes it. But I can't get rid of it because I have a responsive website.
In other browsers it works well.

Please share your experience if you know how to fix it.

Comment: How about `height` or `min-height` `100vh` (viewport height) instead of `100%`?

Comment: @Jax-p thank you for answering.
On the first glance it helped (at least with the minimal example).
Do you know why `100vh` is better `100%` in this case?

Comment: anyone got a link to the Apple bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[@Jax-p answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62717963/5064453)
is valid for the bug I described but it causes another problem.
When you use `100vh` the content starts to be hidden behind the address bar:

[image]

So in my real life app I ended up with a bunch of hacks:

```
document.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => {
  document.documentElement.style.height = `initial`;
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.documentElement.style.height = `100%`;
      setTimeout(() => {
        // this line prevents the content
        // from hiding behind the address bar
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
      }, 500);
  }, 500);
});
```

This hack more or less fixes the problem in iOS Safari 12 and 13

Comment: Why is the outer timeout required?

Comment: The idea is that the outer timeout fixes height when you switch between 'initial' and '100%'. And inner timeout fixes the scroll. Hard to say why Safari needs those time intervals but it worked for me.

Comment: For iOS, you must use WINDOW.addEventListener('orientationchange'...not DOCUMENT.addEventListener...

Comment: Delays as small as 150ms work, but 100ms doesn't, on an iPhone SE.

Comment: BOTH delays are needed.

Comment: @Freddy's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321003/96531) is simple and works! Just want to give it more visibility since this question is getting a bit old.

Answer (score 10):

After spending most of the day dealing with this "feature" (again), I created a CSS-only solution for iOS 14.4 on iPad, iPhone, and works normally on all regular browsers. No hacks required. The secret is to use 100vh on the HTML and BODY elements, while using `position:fixed` on your outermost wrapper element with all of the edges clamped to zero.

Notes: there is a visual artifact when rotating the screen if your BODY background is any different than your wrapper background. This same issue also lets you color the address bar at the top by purposefully giving BODY a different background color (optional).

```css
HTML, BODY {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    /* required to prevent rogue scrollbars */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* cosmetic stuff: */
    background-color:#5AE;
}
#wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  /* if you want the content to scroll normally: */
  overflow: auto;
    /* cosmetic stuff: */
    background-color:#AEA;
    border: #6B6 1em solid;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        Content goes here.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution for the safari browser on iOS 15, where this white space shows up on top of the new tab bar this solution will work.

Answer (score 6):

Mobile browsers usually hide their address bar and controls menu while you scroll (or in some cases when you change from portrait to landscape). It might cause some problems while using `height: 100%;` because sometimes the browser doesn't recalculate percentage values in the right way (it doesn't sum address bar height).

If you want to fill 100% of viewport height you should use `height: 100vh;` (vh = viewport height). I hope it helps.

Comment: When you use this approach, what happens is that the content at the bottom is hidden by the address bar

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No weird hacks required as it's the intended way to solve this problem (not to mention a very simple solution as well).

Answer (score 1):

As I was also searching for a solution to this problem I found this [blog post](https://medium.com/@susiekim9/how-to-compensate-for-the-ios-viewport-unit-bug-46e78d54af0d) with the following solution:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    document.body.height = window.innerHeight;
}
window.onresize(); // called to initially set the height.
```

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me perfectly, on iPhone 15

```css
@media (max-width: 799px) {

  main {
    overflow-x: clip;
    overflow-y: auto;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  }
```